# COM and thread safety

Tags: c#, com, thread-safety, locking

I need to integrate an ASP.NET MVC website with a 3rd party COM application. The code looks something like this:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID);
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
if (!obj.DBOpenedStatus)
{
    obj.InitApplicationContext();
    //do stuff with other COM objects
}
```

The problem is that after a while I start getting `COMExceptions` most probably because I never close that context using `obj.ReleaseApplicationContext()`. So I'm thinking about writing a wrapper implementing `IDisposable` so that I can initialize the context in the constructor and release it when it's disposed. But then I would need a `lock` so that another thread would not close the context while the current thread is still working. The code would look like this:

```
lock (_locker)
{
    using (MyComContextWrapper comContext = new MyComContextWrapper())
    {
        //do stuff with other COM objects
    }
}
```

I know very little about thread safety so what I'm asking you is the following:

1. Is there anything wrong with my approach?
2. Is there anything else I should consider (like deadlocks or something else)?
3. Would you recommend a different approach?

**Edit 1:**
I looked up the progID of the COM class in the registry and found that `ThreadingModel=Apartment` so the COM application uses a `Single-Threaded Apartment` type.

**Edit 2:**
The COM application uses a system to generate ids for objects so that when these objects are persisted in the database they already have an Id. This system involves writing some information in the registry. After a while something goes wrong with this system and I start getting `violation of primary key constraint` errors.

**Edit 3:**
I sometimes get a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type at Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`. Could this be because I'm trying to create a new STA object from another thread?

**Edit 4:**
Someone asked me to post the full the full stack of the `COMExceptions`, but I'm afraid this will make my question too localized and useless for anyone else but me. Furthermore, I actually found the cause of the problem: there were some very rare cases when the context was not initialised before using some com objects and this messed up the system, but the errors only showed up at a later time. So I made sure that the context is always initialized prior to using any com object and the problem went away.

I'm still interested in an answer about thread safety and my proposed solution. Or maybe the question should be closed as too localized?

Comment: What apartment type do you use?

Comment: @Snoopy That's a good question. See my edit.

Comment: http://blogs.srivainc.com/2011/11/running-aspnet-mvc-controller-actions.html

Comment: Please don't make us guess at the exceptions you see, they are crucial to diagnose this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant See my second edit.

Comment: My first guess would be, write a wrapper object around the STA object which is a)stateless b)not using sta, as this is very ineffective inside the iis

Comment: @Snoopy I don't understand your last comment. What is very ineffective inside IIS? If your talking about the lock consider this: I only need to interact with COM objects for adding/editing a user/product/order and not for reading.

Comment: as far as i remember, iis has a fixed amount of workerthreads, a call to an STA object blocks such a thread. if all threads are blocked, no new connections can be processed.

Comment: You are getting a dbase engine error.  I very seriously doubt this has anything to do with threading, given that COM already ensures that the methods run on the same thread on which the COM object got created.  Contact the owner the COM code to get support.

Comment: @HansPassant Can 2 STA COM objects get created and run on different threads? If they can, I think that's the cause of the problem. Do you agree?

Comment: @david.s An outstanding article on STA nuances can be found [at this location](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9190/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment-Pa). To answer your question whether two  STA objects can reside in two distinct respective STAs in the same MTA process, the answer is yes, they can. If you're using an MTA system and an STA is required for an object COM will create one for you. Do it again from a different thread, and COM can do it again for you. This is demonstrable with some pretty basic boilerplate test code.

Comment: Please put the full stack of the COMExceptions (or other errors you are seeing).

Comment: @SimonMourier See Edit 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a lock around your objects as the whole purpose of COM Threading is making your life easier and automatic (once you understand its use, and if the registry is correct) in multi-threading environments.

In standard managed .NET scenarios, you don't need to do anything specific either, even releasing the COM object should be done automatically by the garbage collector. So you shouldn't need a using pattern.

That being said, it may be possible that the underlying unmanaged COM object works better when it's released once used, or maybe your application can't really wait for the GC to happen for some reason (because of a hi usage for example). In these scenarios, you can use [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) or [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) to force the release of the COM object once used, and wraps it using a wrapper object.